# Pass parameter from list to viewmodel constructor

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

I have a list of Players

```
public ObservableCollection<PlayerModel> Players { get; set; }
```

A flexlayout bindable items is set to players list

```
<FlexLayout x:Name="playerscollection" Wrap="Wrap" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Players}"/>
```

The items view is a separate content view "PlayerView" with ViewModel "PlayerVieModel" that has a parametrized constructor.

PlayerView =>

```
<ContentView.Content>

        <StackLayout>


        <StackLayout  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >

            <Entry x:Name="entry" Placeholder="الاسم" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Text="{Binding PlayerName}" />
            <Label  TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="اللاعب" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <views:SportsListView x:Name="sportsList" BindingContext="{Binding ListViewModel}"   
                                              HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                              Pickervisibility="True"/>

        <Label x:Name="payment" Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference sportsList}, Path=BindingContext.SportsTotalPayments, StringFormat='{0:D2}'}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Margin="0,0,10,0" Padding="0" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="20"/>


    </StackLayout>

</ContentView.Content>

public PlayerViewModel(bool showPicker = true, PlayerModel player = null){}
```

I need to bind the list view items to the PlayerVieModel

```
<FlexLayout x:Name="playerscollection" Wrap="Wrap" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Players}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <views:PlayerView >
                <views:PlayerView.BindingContext>
                    <viewModels:PlayerViewModel>
                        <x:Arguments>
                                <x:Boolean>false</x:Boolean>
                                <models:PlayerModel/>
                            </x:Arguments>
                    </viewModels:PlayerViewModel>
                </views:PlayerView.BindingContext>
            </views:PlayerView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</FlexLayout>
```

But PlayerModel is always null. So, I used the biniding for the model

```
            <viewModels:PlayerViewModel>
                <x:Arguments>
                        <x:Boolean>false</x:Boolean>
                        <models:PlayerModel 
                            PlayerName="{Binding Source={x:Reference playerscollection},Path=PlayerName}" 
                            PlayerPayment="{Binding Source={x:Reference playerscollection},Path=PlayerPayment}" 
                            Sports="{Binding Source={x:Reference playerscollection},Path=Sports}" />
                    </x:Arguments>
            </viewModels:PlayerViewModel>
```

It Gives Error Missmatch x:argument

Comment: Does `views:PlayerView`  contain `Listview`? Can you share this part of code? Or `playerscollection` is the name of the `Listview`.

Comment: I added the PlayerView XAML...."playerscollection" refers to flexlayout listview

Comment: Why not add the bindingContext `this.BindingContext = new MyPlayerViewModel(false, new PlayerModel() );` in your background code? I add your `PlayerView` code. then I make a test with `PlayerName` in the `Entry`. it worked as normal. Here is running screenshot. https://imgur.com/a/3LBRxrb

Comment: I need to pass each item in players collecion in flexlayout items into Playerview

Comment: Is binding other viewMoel In your FlexLayout page? If so, you can add the `BindingContext = new MyPlayerViewModel(false, new PlayerModel() )` in the PlayerView directly, When you add it to FlexLayout page, all of the `PlayerView` will have it.

Comment: This will pass an empty Playermodel, so the flexlayout will be list of empty playerview (empty name - empty sport list). Even the flexlayout has the list but not binded to contents

Comment: Do you want to transfer the PlayerModel from ContentPage to ContentView? You can add the properties in the ContentView, then binding it in the Contentview like this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990624/when-to-use-xamarin-bindings-as-opposed-to-passing-objects-to-page-constructors